# Need help IF ISPICKVAL Formula field

Tags: picklist, formula-field

I have a checkbox and picklist field.I want to have a formula field which evaluates that the checkbox is checked and will assign different values based on user selected picklist field value.

Here is my formula:

```
(IF(Cognos_BI_Access_Required__c,
    IF(
        OR(
            ISPICKVAL(Project__c, "ITS"),
            ISPICKVAL(Project__c, "Tax Dashboard"),
            ISPICKVAL(Project__c, "VEASI")
        ),
        "ITS Developers/ITS report testers",
        "Corporate Tax",
        "CR_VEASI_USERS"
    ),
    None)
)
```

But I am getting the below error :

> Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 4

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you're actually looking for CASE, which allows you to map one value to another. Your formula should probably look like this:

```
IF(Cognos_BI_Access_Required__c,
    CASE(TEXT(Project__c), 
        "ITS", "ITS Developers/ITS report testers",
        "Tax Dashboard", "Corporate Tax",
        "VEASI", "CR_VEASI_USERS",
        NULL),
    NULL
)
```

Answer (score 2):

The syntax is:

```
IF(logical_test, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

So for one `IF` statement:

```
IF(/*condition 1*/), "Value if true", "Value if false")
```

For nested `IF` statements:

```
IF(/*condition 1*/, "Value if condition 1",
    IF(/*condition 2*/, "Value if condition 2", "Value if not condition 2")
)
```

In the above:

- `condition 1` represents `Cognos_BI_Access_Required__c`
- `condition 2` represents your `OR` clause
- It is unclear based on your OP how to map the text values.

---

If you are trying to specify an if/else chain for one field `CASE` is the appropriate mechanism, as also mentioned by [@sfdcfox](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/users/2984/sfdcfox). The syntax is:

```
CASE(expression,​value1, result1, value2,​ result2,...,​ else_result)
```

Here:

- `expresion` represents `Project__c`
- `result1` represents `"ITS"`

  - `value1` represents `"ITS Developers/ITS report testers"`
- `result2` represents `"Tax Dashboard"`

  - `value2` represents `"Corporate Tax"`
- `result3` represents `"VEASI"`

  - `value3` represents `"CR_VEASI_USERS"`
- You haven't really discussed, but `else_result` should likely be `null`.

Comment: Thanks @Adrian Larson!!

The outer if condition will check if the checkbox Cognos_BI_Access_Required__c is checked and then the nested if statement will check Project__c is equal to ITS , then the formula field(Group__c) will  return text value ITS Developers/ITS report testers...

If the issue is clarified can u rectify the formula?